# Enabling Extensions

Tags: ldap, php

I am changing some of my PHP settings such as upload size limit etc.

I manage to increase my upload size limit with some modifications to my Loaded Configuration File: php5.ini.

So it is the right file, and changes to php5.ini takes effect.

I want to enable ldap extension too. However, i couldnt do that. I added the following line:
extension=php_ldap.dll

But it did not take any effect.

Can anybody see why?
Thanks!

Comment: I am hesitated to ask, what operation system your server runs on?

Comment: What does your server log say? Does the extension show up in [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)?

Comment: according to my phpinfo: it is Linux. Ldap extension does not show up in phpinfo. Some extensions are there by default but not ldap. And may I ask where can i read my server log?

Comment: @user - Can you try looking in your PHP ext directory to make sure it exists? - Also have you restarted Apache after adding the ext to php.ini?

Comment: It's a share hosting plan and i have no access to PHP's Configuration File. I can access to php's Loaded Configuration File and when i make some changes (mentioned above) they take effect (after 10 min) so i guess there is no need to restart the apache (besides unfortunately i do not have a permission to do that too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Linux, adding a dll extension won't do much good since these are used by Windows.
You'd rather have to enable the .so extension.

But then again just uncommenting or adding this entry in your php.ini doesn't make the extension work automatically, it will work only if the given .so file is really there and is in the right path, resp. the path is configured correctly.

If you're on Linux and you've got a chance, you should install extensions via your package manager (apt, yum, ...) which will compile the extension into your php installation. This way you won't loose your extension after server updates which include php.

If you don't have access to your server, there is always something you can do!

a) Ask the hosting provider to enable the extension for you, good hosting providers do that.
b) Get a VPS. You'll be so much better off!! It's worth it! Check out ServerGrove!

Comment: i tried to enable the .so extension but as you said it didnt make the extension work. I guess the .so file is not there. I dont have an access to extension file nor i can install additional one. So i guess there is nothing much i can do about this issue.

Comment: thanks for the tips, it is godaddy so i guess they can help me.